# Matrix Point-Wise Vector Multiplication

Tags: matrices, vectors

I have the following equation, where $\mathbf{M}$ denotes a singular Square Matrix (dim= $n$ x $n$), $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ denote vectors (with dimension $n$, too). The operator $\odot$ denotes point-wise multiplication.

$$
\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{M} (\mathbf{x} \odot \mathbf{y}).
$$
The goal is to get $\mathbf{M}\mathbf{y}$, where ${\bf b, M}$, and ${\bf x}$ are known and fixed. 
The problem is that I cannot find rules or examples where matrix multiplication and point-wise vector multiplication happen at the same time. Here, I have a point-wise multiplication between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ and then a normal matrix-vector multiplication with $\mathbf{M}$. Moreover, $\mathbf{M}$ is singular which makes my issue even more difficult.

Does anybody have an idea how I can get $\mathbf{M}\mathbf{y}$ (or $\mathbf{y}$)? This would be awesome :)

Comment: If you can freely choose $x$, you can let $x$ be the all $1$'s vector. Also note that you can write $x \odot y$ as $M_xy$, where $M_x$ is the diagonal matrix obtained by putting the entries of $x$ along the main diagonal, and $0$'s elsewhere. If that doesn't help, some more context might be in order.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I also had the idea to model the vector $x$ as a diagonal matrix, but I couldn't find a way to get $My$. The vector $b$ and $x$ are known, the matrix $M$ also. The vector $y$ is not known. All values are real values. So if I get $y$, I have $My$ of course. But $My$ is sufficient. The equation is part of a longer derivation in a signal processing proof, so I am not sure which context is needed?

Comment: I think that should do it; just mentioning that $b, x,$ and $M$ are known and presumably fixed, while $y$ is not. You may want to add that to the question, since that cleared things up for me.